# Mocking formController in directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a directive that checks for the validity of the form before doing something. It's working, but my unit tests keep on failing because I can't mock the formController in my karma tests.

I have the following directive:

```
.directive('directiveName', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'form',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.bind('submit', function(event) {
                if(!ctrl.$valid) ...do something here...
            }
        }
    };
});
```

This is my test initialization:

```
var form, element, $scope; 

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $q) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var template = angular.element('<form fl-submit="mockFunction()">' +
                          '<button type="submit"> </button> </form>');

    $scope.mockFunction = function() {
      return promise.promise;
    };

    element = $compile(template)($scope);
    form = $scope.form;
}));

describe('and the form is not valid', function() {
    form.$valid = false;
    ...expect something here...
});
```

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: where are you using `'directiveName'` directive in test ? what is `promise.promise` and shouldn't it be `deferred.promise` ? and you are not resolving promise anywhere

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem? I'm having the same issue.